# Scrapy - invalid predicate when building xpath response from other text on page

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, lxml

Trying to scrape data from pages where the table id is built from the text on the page. Since each page has different text, the table id is unique to each page. I'm able to get the table id by putting strings together but can't get the id to work in my xpath statement.

When I hard code the table id in the statement below I get a successful response

```
for zodiac in response.xpath('//table[@id="Taurus-the-Bull"]/tbody/tr'):
```

but when I try to build the id from the strings on the page

```
theid = "Taurus-the-Bull"

for zodiac in response.xpath('//table[@id=f"{theid}"]/tbody/tr'):
```

I keep getting `ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //table[@id=f"{theid}"]/tbody/tr` & I don't know why? I'm pretty sure `f"{theid}"`evaluates to `Taurus-the-Bull` but don't know why the xpath error exists...

Comment: For an f-string the f should go before the entire string

Answer (score 0):

I think you did use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) in a wrong way - you should put `f` in the beginning of the string. So this is what you should write:

```
for zodiac in response.xpath(f'//table[@id="{theid}"]/tbody/tr'):
```

Comment: thanks @Serhii Shynkarenko, I'm now able to get a response